# Expose a view with no key using OData (Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v8.2)?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view, odata

I have a view with no key coming from SQL Server via Entity Framework.  I'd like to expose this view via OData, but haven't found the winning formula yet.  Can someone either explain how to do this or point me to a tutorial or something that can help?

There are two significant pieces I'm not sure enough on:  the "model builder" part and the backing controller.

Comment: Please provide more detail and specific examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're right - that wasn't much to go on.  However, I can state the question quite simply.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started is an excellent tutorial on how to get OData working for a nice, simple, clean solution.  What I need is essentially identically to that, but with "Customer" having no key.  I have set up a repository with the code from the above link at https://github.com/plettb/SimpleODataExample.  If you clone that repository, rename "Customer.Id" to "RandomProperty", and get it working, you'll have answered my question. :)

Comment: P.S. Why can't I put line breaks in the comments?!?